# Quotes around dynamic expression Groovy SQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, groovy

I am doing a query to my database using Groovy, the query is working perfectly and bringing back the correct data however I get this error in my terminal.

> In Groovy SQL please do not use quotes around dynamic expressions
>   (which start with $) as this means we cannot use a JDBC
>   PreparedStatement and so is a security hole. Groovy has worked around
>   your mistake but the security hole is still there.

Here is my query

```
sql.firstRow("""select elem
                        from site_content,
                        lateral jsonb_array_elements(content->'playersContainer'->'series') elem
                        where elem @> '{"id": "${id}"}'
                     """)
```

If I change it to just $id or

```
sql.firstRow("""select elem
                        from site_content,
                        lateral jsonb_array_elements(content->'playersContainer'->'series') elem
                        where elem @> '{"id": ?}'
                     """, id)
```

I get the following error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range:
>   1, number of columns: 0.

Comment: Could you please try: ```sql.firstRow("""select elem
                        from site_content,
                        lateral jsonb_array_elements(content->'playersContainer'->'series') elem
                        where elem @> '{"id": ?}'
                     """, [id])```, `[id]` instead of `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Positional` or `named` parameters are handled by groovy sql properly and should be used instead of `"'$id'"`.

As @Opal mentioned and as described [here](http://groovy-lang.org/databases.html), you should be passing your params either as a `list` or `map`:

```
sql.execute "select * from tbl where a=? and b=?", [ 'aa', 'bb' ]
sql.execute "select * from tbl where a=:first and b=:last", first: 'aa', last: 'bb'
```